# Passing an uninitialized array to a function in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Purpose of my program is simple, to read sequence of int numbers from file, here's the code:

```
int main()
{
   FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

   int *array = NULL; // Declaration of pointer to future array;
   int count;

   process_file(file, array, &count);

   return 0;
}

// Function returns 'zero' if everything goes successful plus array and count of elements as arguments
int process_file(FILE *file, int *arr, int *count)
{
    int a;
    int i;
    *count = 0;

    // Function counts elements of sequence
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &a) == 1)
    {
        *count += 1;
    }

    arr = (int*) malloc(*count * sizeof(int)); // Here program allocates some memory for array

    rewind(file);

    i = 0;
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &a) == 1)
    {
        arr[i] =  a;
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is, in outer function (main), array haven't changed.
How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the array by reference, so that the function can change its caller's array.

It must be:

```
process_file(FILE *file, int **arr, int *count)
```

and call like so:

```
process_file(file, &array, &count);
```

Additionally, I would suggest:

- Using `size_t` rather than `int` for the array length.
- [Not casting the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
- Computing size like so: `*array = malloc(*count * sizeof *array);`, this avoids repeating `int`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "*array = malloc(*count * sizeof **array);"?

Comment: thanks, it works with some adjustment: to assign value to array's element in function i need to make it like this (*array)[i] = value